# LIst of all region format

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

i'm be able to retrieve the region format of the user, ad example it_IT with this code

```
[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier];
```

is it possible have the complete list of these identifier?

```
(it_IT, de_DE, de_AT,....)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NSLocale availableLocaleIdentifiers] is yet another way.

For testing, specifically to insure all date formats are handled properly in my UI, I rip through that array, set a NSDateFormatter to use that and test for every possible combination of date formatting in an automated way.

Interesting what you learn along the way as well when you see some date representations that break your assumptions about how some dates, day names, etc might be formatted.

Comment: Many thanks RunningPink, works. The only problem that is without order. is not possible have a list with the iso country code fro example "de" and all the regional format in sequences "de_AT", "de_DE" and so on? Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

- Returns an array of NSString objects that represents all known legal ISO currency codes.

  [NSLocale ISOCurrencyCodes];
- Returns an array of NSString objects that represents all known legal country codes.

  [NSLocal ISOCountryCodes];
- Returns an array of NSString objects that represents all known legal ISO language codes.

  [NSLocale ISOLanguageCodes];

All the info from:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks Antonio MG, i've trid to do this but return just only the iso country code like it,de,fr,en and not the regional format it_IT, de_DE.